# Error: unable to load client certificate private key file

Tags: ios, certificate, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to check if my certificate is correct and trying to do a handshake with:

openssl s_client -connect gateway.push.apple.com:2195 -cert cert.pem -key privateKey.pem

I am getting an error:

unable to load client certificate private key file
4452410816:error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line:crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:745:Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY